How to fix wrong: 'void org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.publish.ArchivePublishArtifact.<init>(org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask)'
i am trying to run the following command gradlew assemble to run the backend of this open source project,https://github.com/jmprathab/MyHome, and when i do that i get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
'void org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.publish.ArchivePublishArtifact.(org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask)'
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1s
Watched directory hierarchies: []

I am confused on how to get this right someone please help.
The following is my build.gradle file for reference:

plugins {
  id "idea"
  id "org.openapi.generator"
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation "io.swagger:swagger-annotations:${swaggerAnnotationsVersion}"
  implementation "javax.validation:validation-api:${javaxValidationApiVersion}"
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:${fasterXmlJacksonAnnotationsVersion}"
  implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
  implementation "org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:${jacksonDatabindNullableVersion}"
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${springFoxVersion}"
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${springFoxVersion}"
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:${springFoxVersion}"
  implementation "org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:${springBootVersion}"

  compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
  annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
}

task generateOpenApiSpec(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
  generatorName = "spring"
  inputSpec = "$projectDir/src/main/resources/public/swagger/api.yaml".toString()
  outputDir = "$buildDir/generated".toString()
  apiPackage = "com.myhome.api"
  invokerPackage = "com.myhome.utils"
  modelPackage = "com.myhome.model"
  typeMappings = [
          'bigdecimal': 'java.math.BigDecimal'
  ]

  additionalProperties = [
          "skipDefaultInterface": "true",
          "interfaceOnly"       : "true",
          "booleanGetterPrefix" : "is",
          "useTags"             : "true"
  ]
  importMappings = [
          'Pageable': 'org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable',
          'PageInfo': 'com.myhome.utils.PageInfo'
  ]
}
compileJava.dependsOn(generateOpenApiSpec)

def generatedSourcesDir = file("build/generated/src/main/java")
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'build/generated/src/main/java'
    }
  }
}
idea {
  module {
    sourceDirs += generatedSourcesDir
    generatedSourceDirs += generatedSourcesDir
  }
}


Did you find the solution to this? I am running into the same issue while upgrading my Java11-springboot2-gradle4 application to java21-springboot3-gradle8.5.

You should use right java version, see
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html
